# Gaussian integration theorem for a rectangle

Tags: vector-fields, gaussian-integral

I need to show the Gaussian integration theorem for a rectangle R = ]a, b[ x ]c, d[ in the two-dimensional real numbers.

I have seen many examples using a vector field and calculating the divergence from these field. But the problem I have to solve, doesn't has any given vector field.

How can I show the equality of the two integrals in the Gaussian integration theorem without having concrete values? I was asked to show the iterated integrals directly, but I don't understand exactly what it means.

Kindly regards

Comment: What kind of function are you supposed to use? Or if no information is given about the function, can it be that you have to write down a generic formula?

Comment: I don't have any function, only the given rectangle. This is the problem I am facing, because I don't know how to get such a generic formula.

Comment: How about for instance this page: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/divergence-theorem-articles/a/2d-divergence-theorem ?